# Angular, graphql apollo error - how to define a custom merge function?

Tags: angular, typescript, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have angular apollo and i have predefined some values in **apolloCache** :

```
function mergeFields(existing: any, incoming: any) {
  return {...existing, ...incoming};
}

function relaceFields(existing: any, incoming: any) {
  return incoming;
}

  apolloCache = new InMemoryCache({
    possibleTypes: possibleTypesResult.possibleTypes,
    typePolicies: {
        Query: {
            fields: {
                eligibleShippingMethods: {
                    merge: relaceFields,
                },
            },
        },
        Product: {
            fields: {
                customFields: {
                    merge: mergeFields,
                },
                
            },
        },
        Collection: {
            fields: {
                customFields: {
                    merge: mergeFields,
                },
            },
        },
        Order: {
            fields: {
                lines: {
                    merge: relaceFields,
                },
                shippingLines: {
                    merge: relaceFields,
                },
                discounts: {
                    merge: relaceFields,
                },
                shippingAddress: {
                    merge: relaceFields,
                },
                billingAddress: {
                    merge: relaceFields,
                },
            },
        },
        Customer: {
            fields: {
                addresses: {
                    merge: relaceFields,
                },
                customFields: {
                    merge: mergeFields,
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

But now i am getting the error :

> Cache data may be lost when replacing the values field of a
> ManagedFilter object.
>
> This could cause additional (usually avoidable) network requests to
> fetch data that were otherwise cached.
>
> To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), define
> a custom merge function for the ManagedFilter.values field, so
> InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects:
>
> existing: [   {
> "__ref": "ManagedFilterValue:276"   },   {
> "__ref": "ManagedFilterValue:260"   },   {
> "__ref": "ManagedFilterValue:247"   },   {
> "__ref": "ManagedFilterValue:254"   },   {
> "__ref": "ManagedFilterValue:253"   },   {
> "__ref": "ManagedFilterValue:230"   } ]   incoming: [   {
> "__ref": "ManagedFilterValue:260"   } ]
>
> For more information about these options, please refer to the
> documentation:
>
> - Ensuring entity objects have IDs:
>   https://go.apollo.dev/c/generating-unique-identifiers   * Defining
>   custom merge functions:
>   https://go.apollo.dev/c/merging-non-normalized-objects

I am calling this :

```
Query.search(
input: SearchInput!
): SearchResponse!
```

Which response is :

```
type SearchResponse {
items: [SearchResult!]!
totalItems: Int!
facetValues: [FacetValueResult!]!
collections: [CollectionResult!]!
topFilters: [ManagedFilter!]!
leftFilters: [ManagedFilter!]!
}
```

As you can see there is topFilters and leftFilters ManagedFilter types :

```
type ManagedFilter {
id: ID!
languageCode: LanguageCode!
name: String!
code: String!
values: [ManagedFilterValue!]!
}
```

and the values type :

```
type ManagedFilterValue {
id: ID!
languageCode: LanguageCode!
filterId: ID!
name: String!
code: String!
count: Int
}
```

**How can i add ManagedFilter or ManagedFilterValue to the apolloCache typePolicies so i would not be getting this error message from appollo client ?**